# Proving integrality of a sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

How would one go about proving whether or not the terms of a sequence such as the following
$$1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 21, 181, 5221, 1090981, 986241401, 51490676208426,\ldots$$
defined by
$$a_na_{n-5}=a_{n-1}(a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4})+a_{n-2}(a_{n-3}+a_{n-4})+a_{n-3}a_{n-4},$$
with $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_5=1$, are always integers? I have checked the first 50 terms using Mathematica, but the numbers get huge pretty fast and my poor old pc cannot compute much more than that.

By the way, in the general case
$$a_na_{n-k}=a_{n-1}(a_{n-2}+\ldots+a_{n-k+1})+a_{n-2}(a_{n-3}+\ldots+a_{n-k+1})+\ldots+a_{n-k+2}a_{n-k+1},$$
with $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_k=1$, it seems to be the case that sequences generated with even $k$ quickly get non-integer terms.

Realated: [Somos sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos_sequence).

Comment: Where does this come from? Just curious... (and it might give a clue to a proof).

Comment: @vonbrand I was reading about Somos sequences and I wanted to see if I could come up with something similar. Basically I just fooled around in Mathematica until I found something that seemed to be integral :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Section 7.6 of [Alman, Cuenca and Huang](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0751), I extract the following proof without insight:

Define
$$b_m = \frac{a_m + a_{m+1} + a_{m+2} + a_{m+3} + a_{m+4}}{a_{m+1} a_{m+3}}.$$

A computer algebra system checks that $b_m = b_{m+2}$ (this is just an equality between two rational functions of $(a_m, a_{m+1}, a_{m+2}, a_{m+3}, a_{m+4})$.) In our case, $b_i$ alternates $5$, $10$, $5$, $10$, etcetera.

In particular, we have the recursion
$$a_{m+4} = (\mbox{$5$ or $10$}) \cdot a_{m+1} a_{m+3} - a_m - a_{m+1} - a_{m+2} - a_{m+3}$$
whose values are plainly integral.

Comment: This looks very interesting, but it seems to be quite far beyond my current mathematical abilities. I'm familiar with most of the material in Artin's Algebra and I know some combinatorics. Do you have any suggestion what to study in order to understand this material better? Any thing more specific than more algebra?

Answer (score 3):

This is Theorem 3.9.(6) of [Alman, Cuenca and Huang](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0751) with $n=5$ and $A=B=0$. I'm afraid I do not understand their proof well enough to say more.

---

I can say a little more to fill in context. Everything that I am saying is also in the introduction to Alman, Cuenca and Huang. A stronger property than integrality is Laurentness: Define rational functions $x_i$ by making $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$ formal variables and then setting
$$x_n = \frac{\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 4} x_{n-i} x_{n-j}}{x_{n-5}}.$$
Laurentness is the claim that all of these rational functions have denominators that are monomials in $(x_1, \ldots, x_5)$. In particular, we plug in $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5) = (1,1,1,1,1)$, then all the terms are integral

Fomin and Zelevinsky, in their ["caterpillar lemma"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104241) describe a general recursive set up with the following properties: One starts with $((x_1, \ldots, x_n), (P_1, \ldots, P_n)$ where $P_i$ are polynomials in the $x_i$ obeying certain compatabilities. One then chooses an index $i$ to "mutate" at. One replaces $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ by $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x'_i, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_n)$ where
$$x'_i = \frac{P_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n)}{x_i}.$$
One also replaces $(P_1, \ldots, P_n)$ by modified polynomials according to a recipe which is too complex to give here. The caterpillar lemma then says that, no matter how many times you perform this operation, you will get $x$'s which are Laurent in the original $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. [Lam and Pylyavskyy](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2611) made certain technical improvements on Fomin and Zelevinsky, and ACH actually use the Lam-Pylyavskyy formalism.

In particular, suppose that the FZ recipe, when mutating at $x_1$, turns $(P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n)$ into $(P_n, P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_{n-1})$. One could then periodically mutate at $1$, $2$, $3$, ..., $n$, $1$, $2$, ..., $n$, ... You will then get a sequence $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., which obeys the Laurentness property, defined by the recursion
$$x_m = \frac{P_1(x_{m-n+1},\ldots, x_{m-1})}{x_{m-n}} \quad (\ast).$$
Conversely, given a Laurent sequence of the form $(\ast)$, one can wonder whether $P_1$ can be extended to an $n$-tuple $(P_1, \ldots, P_n)$ so the the FZ operation turns it into $(P_n, P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_{n-1})$.

When this can be done, Alman, Cuenca and Huang say that $P_1$ is $1$-periodic. They give an algorithm to test whether a polynomial is $1$-periodic, and Theorem 3.9 lists several cases they have discovered using their algorithm.

Comment: Trying to work out the terminology that is in general use; it would appear that they are saying this sequence stays integral for any initial sextuple with $a_1 a_6 = a_2 a_3 + a_2 a_4 + a_2 a_5 + a_3 a_4 + a_3 a_5 + a_4 a_5,$ perhaps because $a_7$ can be written as a polynomial $P(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)$ with integral coefficients?

Comment: Not stays integral; has only denominators that divide $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$.

Comment: Alright, so, fixing a middle four, it matters how we factor into $a_1 a_6;$ if $a_1 = 1,$ it stays integral, but the other extreme $a_6 = 1$ we may get denominators out of a finite set...

Comment: No, $a_1=1$ does not give integrality. Starting with $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5) = (1,2,3,4,5)$, the denominators of the $a_i$ are $\{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 24, 144, 128, 9216, 3538944, 1358954496, 33397665693696 \}$. The point is that, even though the numerators are divisible by some gargantuan primes, the denominators are all of the form $2^a 3^b 5^c$ -- the factors of $a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5$.

Comment: Oh, not $\gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3,a_4, a_5),$ rather the collection of primes that divide any of them, also with no exponent bounds...so, if $w = a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5,$ then a denominator is a divisor of some $w^k$

Comment: Right. I now understand the ACH paper well enough to extract a proof without understanding, see my other answer. Note that, if we start with general $a_i$, the $b_i$ defined in that answer will be rational, but only primes dividing $a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5$ will appear in their denominators, so only such primes can occur in the denominators of the $b_i$.